# Apache Nifi : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository (No such file or directory)

Tags: apache-nifi

I am facing below issue and all of my flows are getting failed.

PSB the issue:
IOException thrown from ExecuteSQLRecord: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository/325/1640693707361-201029 (No such file or directory)

Please help.

Comment: It looks like something's wrong with your content repository and it's not finding the content that flowfiles refer to. Did you move it, change permissions or empty it manually?

Comment: yes, since data was getting filled, i deleted some of the files.